# DontSpawnIfColliding doesn't check actor spawn by the SpawnActor function

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

```
 void USpawner::Spawn(TSubclassOf<AMyActor> myactor)
 {
     UWorld* World = GEngine->GameViewport->GetWorld();
     ACharacter* myCharacter = UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerCharacter(World, 0);
     FVector loc = myCharacter->GetActorLocation();
     FActorSpawnParameters ActorSpawnParameters;
     ActorSpawnParameters.SpawnCollisionHandlingOverride = ESpawnActorCollisionHandlingMethod::DontSpawnIfColliding;

     AMyActor* NewActor = World->SpawnActor<AMyActor>(myactor, loc, FRotator::ZeroRotator, ActorSpawnParameters);
 }
```

This code works fine to spawn the first actor and it checks against existing objects so it doesn't spawn where it may collide with something. However the second time I spawn an object, I notice the object spawning from this function is not taken into account when checking for collisions.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Taking a shot in the dark here but did you check if the collision presets ignore actors from the same class?

Comment: That was the problem thx.

Comment: Oh, great. I'll add it as an answer to give closure to this question and help further coders in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `SpawnActor` method, sometimes the default strategy is not useful. Instead you should both set a *Collision Preset* and (in search for the peace of mind) a *Collision Channel*, double checking the *Collision Response* is not ignoring actors from the same class.